# Scala isInstanceOf and type erasure

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I'm confused as how `isInstanceOf` works in Scala. If I do something like this:

```
val x: Int = 5
x.isInstanceOf[Int]
```

Given that Scala does type erasure, shouldn't the JVM remove all type information during runtime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not **all** type information, just information about **generic types**. Consider this:

```
scala> val l = List("foo")
l: List[String] = List(foo)

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[String]]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]
<console>:9: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type List[String] cannot also be a List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) (but still might match its erasure)
              l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]
                            ^
res1: Boolean = true
```

They both return `true`, because the erased type is `List`.