# How to initialize empty map that has been type aliased

Tags: scala, types, scala-collections, type-alias

Typically I have been declaring a map in this fashion because I need it to be empty

```
var myMap: mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[Objects]] = mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[Objects]]()
```

The object type signature is long so I am trying to declare my own type alias as such in a package object like below.

```
type MyMapType = mutable.Map[String, ListBuffer[Objects]]
```

The problem is when I try to declare my map with the alias it doesn't seem to work.

```
var myMap: MyMapType = MyMapType()
```

I get an error saying

> Expression of type ListBuffer[Objects] doesn't conform to expected type MyPackageObject.MyMapType

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
import collection.mutable.{Map, ListBuffer}
type MyMapType = Map[String, ListBuffer[Object]]
var myMap: MyMapType = Map()
```

**The reason why this works:** `Map()` is shortcut for `Map.apply()`. It's a method invocation on an object called `Map`. It is the companion object of `mutable.Map`. Its name belongs to a completely separate set of identifiers: the names of types are independent from names of objects. Therefore, the companion object `Map` is still called `Map`. Note that you can omit all the type arguments to `.apply()` because of the type inference.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be in a comment but I will ask anyways. When I create a second type like "type MyMapType2 = Map[String, Int]"  and compare it using "myMap.isInstanceOf(MyMapType2)" it returns true. They are both maps however the types they hold are different. Why would it return true?

Comment: @alex [Keyword: "type-erasure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900143/scala-isinstanceof-and-type-erasure).

Answer (score 5):

To write something like `MyMapType()` you need an alias for the companion object in addition to the type:

```
val MyMapType = mutable.Map
```

This isn't quite ideal for this case, but

```
var myMap: MyMapType = MyMapType()
```

will work. Unfortunately,

```
var myMap = MyMapType() // or MyMapType.empty
```

won't. What you really need is

```
object MyMapType {
  // define the methods you want, e.g.
  def apply(items: (String, ListBuffer[Object])*): MyMapType = Map(items: _*)
  def empty: MyMapType = Map.empty
  // etc
}
```

Of course, you can define a method returning such "companion objects".

As a side-note, you usually have either `var` or a mutable collection, both together should be rare.